# Spark storage level "NONE" vs "MEMORY_ONLY"

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I understand that "MEMORY_ONLY" keeps RDDs in cache memory.

What the storage level "NONE" is all about?

Does it mean that every RDD would be recalculated from scratch whenever it is asked for?

What is impact of it and in which scenario this can be useful?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this test case in the code repository:

```
test("cache, getStorageLevel") {
    // test to see if getStorageLevel returns correct value after caching
    withSpark { sc =>
      val verts = sc.parallelize(List((0L, 0), (1L, 1), (1L, 2), (2L, 3), (2L, 3), (2L, 3)))
      val edges = EdgeRDD.fromEdges(sc.parallelize(List.empty[Edge[Int]]))
      assert(edges.getStorageLevel == StorageLevel.NONE)
      edges.cache()
      assert(edges.getStorageLevel == StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    }
}
```

StorageLevel.NONE is the same as no caching. As far as I know a non cached RDD will be recomputed each time depending on the dataflow of the RDD. It seems to be useful for testing purposes and for uncaching a RDD.